# WordPress Action Type

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to determine if a user insert a post in the database

I have here this function

```
add_action("publish_post", "myFunc");

function myFunc(){
    echo "Success!";
}
```

I've tried it on the QuickPress widget and it works fine but in the "Add new post" I didn't get any response.

What action type do I need for the "Add new post" module?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action naame is `save_post` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post). Any functions added on to here can be given the post id as an argument to do what you need.

The down side is that it is called each time a post is saved.

This action is used for saving custom meta box values from the post edit page

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Jamie, I already solved my problem. I just replace "echo" with an insert statement. I think wordpress can't return the string if you are in the "add new post" module

Comment: But I have another problem, 

publish_post always run if a user add or edit a post

I just need myFunc to run when a user add a post, and not to run  when a user edit a post

Comment: you could insert post meta to say that your script has been run the first time, and then each time your script is called, check for the post meta item, if its found, skip your script, else, do your script?